# How can I declare function without ptrsafe in 64bit environmnet?

Tags: vba, vb6, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

My vb6 program was running on 32bit.
Now I have to move it to 64bit.

The lib that I declare below code,the system seem can't get it.
Declare:

```
Public Declare Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" _
Alias "LogonUserA" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, _
ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
ByVal dwLogonType As Long, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Long, _
phToken As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function ImpersonateLoggedOnUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hToken As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function RevertToSelf Lib "advapi32.dll" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
```

Run Code:

```
Public Sub Logon(ByVal strAdminUser As String, ByVal _
    strAdminPassword As String, ByVal strAdminDomain As String)
    Dim lngTokenHandle As Long
    Dim lngLogonType As Long
    Dim lngLogonProvider As Long
    Dim blnResult As Boolean

    lngLogonType = 2
    lngLogonProvider = 0

    blnResult = RevertToSelf()

    blnResult = LogonUser(strAdminUser, strAdminDomain, strAdminPassword, _
    lngLogonType, lngLogonProvider, _
    lngTokenHandle)

    blnResult = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(lngTokenHandle)
    CloseHandle (lngTokenHandle)

End Sub
```

I got the error message

`Error 91:Object variable or With block variable not set`

Almost people say need to add "ptrsafe" after Declare but there is no ptrsafe in vb6.

How can I declare function lib without "ptrsafe" in the 64bit and vb6 ?

Comment: Is this VB6 or VBA?  (You have both languages tagged, but you seem to be discussing VB6.  It might be that people have given you a VBA solution because they thought you were talking about VBA.)

Comment: Some comments from [wikipedia's VB page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) may be pertinent - "Visual Basic development ended with 6.0, but in 2010 Microsoft introduced VBA 7 to provide extended features and add 64-bit support."  And "Although vendor support for Visual Basic 6 has ended, and the product has never been supported on the latest versions of Windows, key parts of the environment still work on newer platforms. It is possible to get a subset of the development environment working on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10."

Comment: You can't compile VB6 to 64-bit. VB6 knows nothing of `PtrSafe`, `LongPtr`, `LongLong`, `CLngLng`.

Comment: Show complete code you use, otherwise nothing may help you.

Comment: who down vote my question? Can tell me where my wrong?

Comment: @GiorgioBrausi Show it, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Almost people say need to add "ptrsafe" after Declare but there is no ptrsafe in vb6.
>   How can I declare function lib without "ptrsafe" in the 64bit and vb6 ?

**VBA** needs to be able to deal with 64 bit Windows when its run within a 64 bit application such as one of the programs from the 64 bit Office suite.

**VB6** runs on its own forever & always as a 32 bit process, it does not need to be 64 bit aware as 64 bit Windows happily emulates 32 bit code with no additional steps required.

Because of this pointer-safe types are not needed, use the 32 bit convention (`Long`) in VB6.

Comment: This is the answer, the VB6-based application will be running as a 32-bit process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the code run under 64bit seems can't understand this dll?

Comment: you need to look at the docs for this functions, work out how they return an error code and see what it is.

Comment: Error 91:Object variable or With block variable not set   seems dll problem?

Comment: Correct Answer! Just need to re-regrsvr32 all dll that i need!

Answer (score 1):

Your functions declarations are wrong.
You don't have to add the complete path for **Lib**, only the library name is need.
By add the path, your code fails on 32 bit OS environment, because `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder doesn't exists on 32 bit systems.

```
Public Declare Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" _
Alias "LogonUserA" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, _
ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
ByVal dwLogonType As Long, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Long, _
phToken As Long) As Long

   Public Declare Function ImpersonateLoggedOnUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hToken As Long) As Long

   Public Declare Function RevertToSelf Lib "advapi32.dll" () As Long

   Public Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
```

See:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248187/how-to-impersonate-a-user-from-active-server-pages

Comment: Make a sample project (with source code of DLL included) that reproduce the error, zip it then public and share the link to download the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about API declarations the following may be helpful. VB6 does not recognize the LongLong data type (64-bit integer) but it can be faked by using the VB6 Currency data type. The Currency numbers are actually stored as 64-bit integers. The four decimal places are only shown in display by dividing the actual number by 10,000. Depending on the specific API calls you are using, you may need to have dual API declarations and select the correct one at run time. So you also need to be able to detect the "bitness" of the system running.

See the following links:

[Detect Bitness](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=9043)

[Faking 64-bit Integers](http://www.jasinskionline.com/Windowsapi/articles/64bit/index.html)